# How to store GridViewDataTextColumn value in Hidden Field in ASPxGridView

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want to store GridViewDataTextColumn value into hidden field.

ASPX

```
  <dx:ASPxGridView ID="dgDepots" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="grid"
        KeyFieldName="LocationCode" Width="100%" OnDataBinding="dgDepots_DataBinding"
        OnRowDeleting="dgDepots_RowDeleting" OnRowInserting="dgDepots_RowInserting" OnRowUpdating="dgDepots_RowUpdating">
        <Columns>
            <dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn FieldName="LocationCode" PropertiesComboBox-ValueField="LocationCode" PropertiesComboBox-TextField="LocationName"
                VisibleIndex="0">
            </dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn>
            <dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn FieldName="CostCenterCode" PropertiesComboBox-ValueField="CostCenterCode" PropertiesComboBox-TextField="CostCenterName"
                VisibleIndex="1">
            </dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn>
            <dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn FieldName="GLCode" PropertiesComboBox-ValueField="GLAccountCode" PropertiesComboBox-TextField="GLAccountName"
                VisibleIndex="2">
            </dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn>
            <dx:GridViewCommandColumn ShowNewButton="true" ShowEditButton="true" ShowDeleteButton="true" VisibleIndex="3">
            </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
        </Columns>
        <%--  <SettingsDetail ShowDetailRow="True" Text='<%# Eval("DistributionPercent") %>' />--%>
        <Styles Header-BackColor="LightBlue" Header-Font-Bold="true">
            <Header BackColor="LightBlue" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Medium">
            </Header>
        </Styles>
        <Templates>
            <DetailRow>
                <dx:ASPxGridView ID="dgCustomers" runat="server" KeyFieldName="CustomerCode"
                    OnBeforePerformDataSelect="dgCustomers_BeforePerformDataSelect" OnDataBinding="dgCustomers_DataBinding"
                    Width="100%" OnRowDeleting="dgCustomers_RowDeleting" OnRowInserting="dgCustomers_RowInserting"
                    OnRowUpdating="dgCustomers_RowUpdating">
                    <Columns>
                        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="CustomerCode" VisibleIndex="0">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtCustCode" runat="server" Width="50px" />
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                        <dx:GridViewDataColumn>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClientClick="return YourJavaScriptFunction();" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" />
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
                        <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="PriceGroupCode" VisibleIndex="1">
                            <EditFormSettings Visible="True" />
                        </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
                        <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="ChannelCode" VisibleIndex="2">
                        </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
                        <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="SubChannelCode" VisibleIndex="3">
                        </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
                        <dx:GridViewCommandColumn ShowNewButton="true" ShowEditButton="true" ShowDeleteButton="true" VisibleIndex="4">
                        </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
                    </Columns>
```

HiddenField :

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdn" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

JS

```
 function YourJavaScriptFunction() {
            $("#<%= hdn.ClientID %>").val($('<%# ((ASPxGridView)Container).FindControl("txtCustCode").ClientID %>').val());
        }
```

Both Button and Text box are present inside Grid view and i want to store text box value inside hidden field

while debugging its showing `null` where i am doing wrong ?

Comment: Can you show all the gridview code?

Comment: what's showing as null? Why don't you place both controls in a variable, look the gridview val first to make sure that its value it coming down correctly. Then if you seeing the gridview value set the hidden field accordingly there.

Comment: @Julián I have added grid view code

Comment: @Julián hidden value in code behind showing null,  Why don't you place both controls in a variable how can i can you give me some sample code for that